# Vb.net query access database table with 2 conditions on the same field

Tags: vb.net

Short background information;

I receive notification emails with an alphanumeric number, a status field, the email receiving time and the sender name.

I have a database which I populated with these outlook emails. E.g.:

```
Number            status     receivingtime           sender
Xyz12345          new        22.01.2019 20:22:16     abc
Xyz5683           new        23.01.2019 15:45:55     abc
Xyz12345          closed     23.01.2019 14:32:30     abc
Xyz8765           new        24.01.2019 16:55:32     abc
Xyz9999           closed     2t.01.2019 09:10:11     abc
```

I need a query (number,status,time,sender) which extracts only the new items if they where not already set to status closed.

In the above given example the extracted data should be xyz5683 and xyz8765
I tried already doing this with for loops which I don't really like as the performance is bad.

I also tried this with populating 2 datatables and joining them together, used except within linq. Due to the fact that I like to store it anywhere for further use I also skipped this method. I would prefer

1.) importing all the emails to the access db

2.) Query them as needed

I read tons of articles with different solutions, but can't figure out how to do this....maybe I already got stuck because I'm thinking way too difficult.

Do you have any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Do you have any experience with SQL at all?  It's just a parameter in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I think that you need only one table and select the data with a "not in" clause. Why you don't try on site https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @bdn02 "not in"? Huh?

Comment: What is the table name and what database are you using?

Comment: Select * From EmailTable Where status = 'new';

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Access, so my first solution will give you what you want to see.

At the top of your screen on the ribbon/toolbar, you can create a query.  Create > Query Design > Close button > SQL View on ribbon.

First, create a new query called "closed" with the SQL as:

```
Select Distinct [Number] From status_table where status = 'closed'
```

Then, create what is called a **mismatch query**:

```
Select st.[Number], st.status, st.receivingtime, st.sender From status_table as st
    Left Join closed as cls on st.[Number] = cls.[Number]
Where cls.[Number] Is Null;
```

The query will only show rows which are not closed.  You can also try the "Find Unmatched Query Wizard" and follow the steps to remove closed items from your list. You will still need to create the query called "closed" before running the wizard.

If you have SQL Server, you can do this in one query:

```
With cls As  --closed items
(Select Distinct [Number] 
    From status_table where status = 'closed')
Select st.[Number], status, receivingtime, sender From status_table st
    Left Join cls on st.[Number] = cls.[Number]
Where cls.[Number] Is Null;
```

This example is for Microsoft T-SQL but you can do similar queries in other database types like Oracle, with slightly different syntax.  Performance should be good in most environments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you read the same question I did?

Comment: Thank you.  I certainly did read the same question.  Your suggestion to select "where status = 'new'" will not retrieve the result because one [Number] may show in the table several times; one time when a case is 'new' and one time when it is 'closed'.  Your result will include the ID "Xyz12345", but that ID was closed. So, instead you must exclude any number which has a 'closed' status by using a mismatch query.

Comment: I am trying. :-) So, Xyz12345 should be marked closed? I wonder what number is. An email #, no because there are more than one. A thread maybe.

Comment: Yes, on the first row, Xyz12345 is 'new', then on the third row it is 'closed'.  [Number] is just the name of the first column (where you see Xyz12345).

Comment: Thanks for all your Inputs in between! I made 1 query for all new messages, 1 for all closed to fill 2 data tables to use this data for data grids. I still struggle with the mismatch query. I guess the best solution is to join the 2 data tables at runtime via linq right?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to just create an Access query object using the designer (the query just under where "mismatch query" is in bold above). If you save it as my_query in Access, you can just select from it in vb.Net into a single DataTable holding the result you want.  ex. Select * From my_query.  As you suggest, you can also do this in Linq.  Nice to have options!